# Could not invoke constructor for MapFixture[0] or The instance scriptTableActor.setValueFor. does not exist

Tags: fitnesse

The next problem I have in Fitnesse

WARNING: Cookie "latestContext" does not have a proper "SameSite" attribute value. Soon, cookies without the "SameSite" attribute or with an invalid value will be treated as "Lax". This means that the cookie will no longer be sent in third-party contexts. If your application depends on this cookie being available in such contexts, please add the "SameSite=None" attribute to it. To know more about the "SameSite" attribute, read https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite ExampleSuite.Environment.Acceptance.TestScripts.DesktopDevice.ScopeInsight:27:39 a this is an

ERROR: The Components object is deprecated. It will soon be removed. ExampleSuite.Environment.Acceptance.TestScripts.DesktopDevice.ScopeInsight

java version "1.8.0_202"
Apache Maven 3.9.2
Fitnesse Version 20230823104657
I use the Mozilla Firefox browser

I tried to change the version of maven and java but I couldn't find anything that works for me to be able to run the test

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate of https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/issues/528.

Answer (score 0):

To run the test the compiled Java code needed to be in the right location, this was achieved by changing the Maven command to launch the server.

The cookie warning had nothing to do with that.